# appdeeplink Github .well-known folder not identifying

Tags: android, github

[image]I am adding app deep linking functionality in my app,i followed as per applink assist,i created .well-known folder in github also but still i am facing digital assets link not found

```
  [![<meta-data
            android:name="asset_statements"
            android:resource="@string/asset_statements" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="suresh777.github.io"
                    android:pathPattern="/links" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>][1]][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to create a file named **_config.yml** in your root folder and the value inside is `include: [".well-known"]`

Reference: https://github.com/wojtek-kalicinski/wojtek-kalicinski.github.io