# How to add .well-known on Github Pages files using html

Tags: github-pages

I have a html website on github page, i want to deep link it with my app using .well-known file, the problem is github pages doesn't serve folders starting with a period (eg, .well-known), so I'm unable to verify my domain. I see this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47456627/appdeeplink-github-well-known-folder-not-identifying) but it is not html i try to add `include: [".well-known"]` on _config.yml but it won't solve the problem, i there a solution to this on html.

Comment: is `.well-known` a file or a directory?

Comment: Any repository url ? This can help to debug.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This [here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47456627/appdeeplink-github-well-known-folder-not-identifying?answertab=active#tab-top) but remember to remove the space inside `_config.yml` file make sure there is only 1 line of code like this `include: [".well-known"]` and not like this

```
include: [".well-known"]
```

Make sure you don't have even a white space like this

```
include: [".well-known"]
```

Comment: The extra whitespace doesn't matter

Comment: In my case it was totally opposite. Adding `LF` at the end helped. When it was only 1 line (without `LF` at the end) - it didn't work...

Comment: In my case, removing the white space is what made it work.  Thanks!

Comment: Importantly, `_config.yml` needs to be in the source directory, which might not be the repository root (e.g. in my case, I’m serving up the site from `/docs`). And whitespace doesn’t seem to matter.

Answer (score 1):

## For sites that are NOT using Jekyll:

Add a new empty file called `.nojekyll` to your project

#### Explanation:

Jekyll processing stops the `.well-known` directory from appearing on your live site. The `.nojekyll` file stops this from happening.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file in the name of _config.yml in your root folder and paste following code

> ```
> include:
>   - ".well-known"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that GitHub does serve folders with period(.) but Jekyll is actually blocking that.

https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/22227

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34688925)