# Unable to Access Hidden File on GitHub Pages

Tags: github, http-status-code-404, github-pages, web-hosting

I'm having trouble accessing a hidden file on my GitHub Pages site. I have a file named `cf-2fa-verify.txt` in a hidden directory (`.well-known`) in my repository. I've pushed this file to my repository more than two hours ago, but I'm still getting a 404 error when trying to access it at `[`https://chobegusajumlung.org.np/.well-known/cf-2fa-verify.txt`](https://chobegusajumlung.org.np/.well-known/cf-2fa-verify.txt)`.

But I can access it(

```
.well-known/cf-2fa-verify.txt
```

) from localhost but when I upload it in GitHub, I only get 404 **File not found**

[Screenshot of localhost that has opened /.well-known/cf-2fa-verify.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWCgf.png)

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Checked GitHub's Status: No active incidents reported.

2. Cleared my browser's cache: The issue persists across different browsers and in incognito mode.

3. Checked my repository settings: GitHub Pages is enabled and set to the correct branch.

4. Waited: It's been over two hours since I pushed the changes.

5. Also did research on internet on how to access hidden file from GitHub page but didn't get any useful resources that solves this problem

6. I also asked Microsoft Edge AI(Chat), Chat GPT 3.5, Google Brad. But this also didn't help me. And their last suggestion was to ask in Stack overflow + GitHub Issue etc.

The repository is public.

Here is the link to my repository: [`https://github.com/Ningsang-Jabegu/Kirat-Yakthung-Thegimhang-Chobegu-Sajumlung`](https://github.com/Ningsang-Jabegu/Kirat-Yakthung-Thegimhang-Chobegu-Sajumlung)

I just want to show the file when visiting this url (

```
https://chobegusajumlung.org.np/.well-known/cf-2fa-verify.txt
```

)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add .well-known on Github Pages files using html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55880919/how-to-add-well-known-on-github-pages-files-using-html)

Comment: Your build is failing: https://github.com/Ningsang-Jabegu/Kirat-Yakthung-Thegimhang-Chobegu-Sajumlung/actions

Answer (score 3):

I've found two things have gotten me closer to a solution:

1. Include a `.nojekyll` file as GitHub Pages processing assumes usage of Jekyll. If you are using Jekyll, then your Jekyll config needs an `include` directive for the relevant subfolder (in this case, `.well-known` and;
2. Include an `index.html` or `index.md` file in each subfolder of the file tree. This is **PARTICULARLY** important if you're not using Jekyll, as GitHub Pages doesn't seem to render the folder subtree if those files are missing (my particular use case required a `.well-known/opengpgkey/hu/$KEY` subtree, thus the inclusion of multiple index files).

Comment: Looks like .github folder might be special. I don't seem to get that one published even with `include`.